# Как считать строки и поля у таблицы в jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

У меня есть таблица и я хочу, чтобы при клике на строку TR считывался ее класс и в попапе в поля подставлялись на редактирование значения этой строки, то есть сейчас не могу по наведению (hover) определить класс и под ним считать по атрибутам значения.

```
<tbody align="center" style="background: #fff; height" 25px;" class="d_table">
    <tr class="14">
        <td id="d_table_name">1</td>
        <td id="d_table_family">2</td>
        <td id="d_table_kolvo">3</td>
        <td id="d_table_razmer">4</td>
        <td id="d_table_stats" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">5</td>
        <td id="d_table_aaa">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="15">
        <td id="d_table_name">1</td>
        <td id="d_table_family">2</td>
        <td id="d_table_kolvo">3</td>
        <td id="d_table_razmer">4</td>
        <td id="d_table_stats" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">5</td>
        <td id="d_table_aaa">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="16">
        <td> 111... </td>
        <td> 2... </td> 
        <td> 3... </td>
        <td> 4... </td> 
        <td> 5... </td>
        <td> 6... </td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Так, всем TR я задал одинаковый класс и повесил на него click $('.line_event').click(function() теперь немогу понять как сделать что бы считать из TD - вроде у меня прописаны ИД, а считать не получается, скажите почему не получается сделать вот так ?
var name = $("#d_table_name").val();
alert('line_event'+name);

Answer (score 3):

Две основные ошибки:

1. id - УНИКАЛЬНЫЙ индетификатор и не должен повторяться. Используейте атрибуты.
2. val() работает для инпутов, для получения содержимого ячейки используйте .html()

Вобщем вот рабочий пример: http://jsfiddle.net/SLonoed/UahPM/

Comment: Поправил ссылку на ответ.